# What is root snapshot in Snapshot or EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, amazon-ami

When I try to run a Python script to build an AMI using snapshot it says:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidBlockDeviceMapping) when calling the RegisterImage operation: No root snapshot specified in device mapping.

When I check everything is right. I don't find any root snapshot details in EBS.

```
BlockDeviceMappings=[
            {
                'DeviceName': '/dev/sdb',
                'Ebs': {
                    'SnapshotId': destination_snapshot_id
                },
            },
        ],
        EnaSupport=True,
        Name="jenkins-slave-" + str(int(time.time())),
        VirtualizationType='hvm',
        RootDeviceName='/dev/sda1'
    )
```

Comment: Please, include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: Is your intention to create an AMI from an existing Amazon EC2 instance, or to create it from an existing Amazon EBS snapshot? The first option is the easiest, since you can use `create_image()`.

Comment: i'm trying to do the second one..creating image using ebs snapshot

Answer (score 0):

`RootDeviceName` must match one of the `DeviceName`s in the `BlockDeviceMappings[]`.

In Kanthi K's case, `/dev/sda1` does not match `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: By the way, I stumbled on this because my git-bash was silently replacing `--root-device-name /dev/sda1` with `--root-device-name /Device/Harddisk0/Partition1`. Fixed it with `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`